# Can't access individual element from list in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a simple quiz app which contains a question as `Text` widget and 4 `RaisedButton` widgets for options. This is what I want to create:

[image: quiz]

This my code currently:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              "Flutter Demo Home Page"
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Question(
                questions[questionIndex]["questionText"]
              ),
              Column(
                children: getAnswerList()[questionIndex],
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

getAnswerList():

```
List<List<Answer>> getAnswerList() {
    List<List<Answer>> answerList = [[]];
    for (Map m in questions) {
      List<String> answers = m["answers"];
      List<Answer> temp = [];
      for (String ans in answers) {
        temp.add(
            Answer(
                answerQuestion,
                ans
            )
        );
      }
      answerList.add(temp);
    }
    return answerList;
  }
```

In this function I create temporary list of `Answer` widgets and then add it to `List<List<Answer>>`.

`Question` widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;
  Question(this.questionText);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Text(
        questionText,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

`answerQuestion()` is a method which sets the updated `questionIndex`:

```
void answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex++;
    });
    }
```

Answer widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text(
            answerText
        ),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However the second column widget is not displaying:

[image: error]

Why is the 2nd column not being displayed?

Comment: There are many things missing in your question like: where is `questions` list defined in `getAnswerList `?, where have you defined `answerQuestion`?. Also I would suggest to rename the `Answer` class to something like `Option` as it actually creates an option.

Comment: I have added `Question` widget. I have already added `answerQuestion()` function

Answer (score 0):

the column should contain a list of widgets presently is is not done in the code assign a list of widgets to the children property

Comment: how does this answer the question? give proper details what should be changed

Comment: @A.K.J.94 Can't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please improve your explanation and and code?

Comment: Please improve your answer with more details